# gulp-webserver: Default to index.html if available, else show directories

Tags: gulp

This is my current setup for gulp-webserver.

```
gulp.task('server', function(){
  gulp.src('dist/')
  .pipe(webserver({
    open: true,
    directoryListing: {enable: true},
    fallback: 'index.html'
  }));
});
```

I would like to be able to default to index.html if it is present, otherwise show the directory listing.

Currently this isn't working, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) which has this functionality, and [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to trigger it.

```
gulp.src()
.pipe(shell(([ 
  'ws -d dist/'
]))
```